# Can i know if it is Category first page or 5th?

Tags: categories, pagination

Can i know with pre built wordpress function if it is category's first page or 55th page? For examle first page is `mydomain.com/games/`  and `5th` page is `mydomain.com/games/page/55/`
CAn i determine it with pre built function?

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure it's

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
echo $paged; // "1", "55", or wtv page you're on
```

[`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) is a quick way to retrieve query info from the main global `$wp_query` object.

Comment: Okey i  would like to ask you one question. I use Widget Options Plugin, please google it. It allos me to show specific widget only specific category. For example in /games/ i can show specific widget which will be shown only in this category and not on home page, posts, or any other place. But the Problem is that it shows this widget on first page of category and also on every page on 55th and on 555th pages. But i want to show only on first page on mydomain.com/games/ here and not on pagenations. Do you understand what i mean? How can i do it?